# How can I manage spaces? That is built in the mobile view while I hide an element in my file using html?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How can I the manage spaces , that is built in the mobile view while I hide an element in my file using html?

My content is hidden in the mobile view as I wanted to, but there are some unwanted spaces because of that, how can I remove that?
My code is :

```
<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3 d-none d-sm-block">
```

Comment: Try to add your code in the question, if possible try to recreate your situation in fiddle

Comment: We need more information about the code, as @groovy_guy said you should try to re-create it in fiddle and also add what output you are getting on mobile view, also that 1 line of code may not be the reason that the problem is caused so we need the whole code that you wrote to help you out.

Comment: @groovy_guy I did , but still facing the same issue , how can i get it corrected. Please help

Comment: @Kapoor just one line of code wouldn't be helping us to get you a solution.
If you haven't solved your issue yet,
do include your CSS & js whatever code you've written in your program as well

Comment: @groovy_guy can you help with the problem that is " i have hidden an element for my mobile view , but it has created an awkward space for that , how can i cover that space?